# Truncate comma from python dictionary

Tags: python

Expecting to truncate the `,` from tuple `'x':(11334,)` to int value `'x':11334`. Please check the input and expected output.

Input:

```
q={'x':(11334,),'y':'xtyyyyy','z':12344}
```

Expected output:

```
q={'x':11334,'y':'xtyyyyy','z':12344}
```

Comment: Do you just have one tuple to change or multiple?

Comment: Also, that's invalid syntax for a dict.

Comment: Well, it might be that there is something wrong with the code. It's hard to say, since we have not been shown any of it. We also have not been given a proper explanation of the context for the problem. First off: are you trying to **find out how to do something**, or are you trying to **fix a problem**? Those require different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list(a_tuple)[0]` to get the first element as follow

```py
q={'x':(11334,),'y':'xtyyyyy','z':12344}
print("Input:", q)

q['x'] = list(q['x'])[0]

print("Output:", q)
```

will produce

```
Input: {'x': (11334,), 'y': 'xtyyyyy', 'z': 12344}
Output: {'x': 11334, 'y': 'xtyyyyy', 'z': 12344}
```

Comment: Much more fun: `q['x'], = q['x']`